# CMS Connect Header/Footer on Login Page

Tags: experience-cloud, cms-connect

We have configured CMS Connect in our Experience Cloud site.

We have configured the "Header"/"Footer" URL settings against our source in the "Builder" > "Settings" > "CMS Connect" tab.

After setting this up, does the CMS Header/Footer content appear on our various community pages, except "Login"? Is this a Platform Limitation?

**Can I display the CMS Connect Header/Footer on the Login Page?**
[image: CMS Connect Configuration]

[image: Missing CMS Header/Footer on Login Page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've confirmed with support this is a platform limitation in Experience Cloud. ***CMS Connect content cannot be embedded in Experience Builder OOTB Login/Registration/Forgot Password/etc Pages***.

This limitation is not documented.